# Navigation to another view in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, navigation

here is  my code , i am trying to get from one view to another without any memory leaks.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    firstviewcontroller *first = [[firstviewcontroller alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:first.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(IBAction)gotosecondview:(id)sender
{ 
    secondviewcontroller *second = [[secondviewcontroller alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:second.view];
    [second release];
}

-(IBAction)gotofirstview:(id)sender
{
    [self.view  removeFromSuperview];
}
```

to make the above code work without crashing , all i have to do is remove `[second release]`.
if I remove it I get memory errors  (build and analyze) . how can i solve this problem. and i dont want to use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];` 
all i am trying to do i navigating from one view to another and vice versa WITHOUT using navigation controller.  my firstviewcontroller and secondviewcontroller are of type `UIViewController`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the current view controller alive while its view is showing (so it can process the user input, etc.).

In your code, you can achieve that in several ways:

- Keep an instance of `firstviewcontroller` and `secondviewcontroller` as instance variables, and release them on the `dealloc` method.
- Keep an instance variable with the currently in use `UIViewController` and release it when you switch to another view.

The code for the second option would look something like this:

```
@interface
    UIViewController *currentViewController;
@end

@implementation

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    firstviewcontroller *first = [[[firstviewcontroller alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self switchToViewController:first];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)switchToViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController {
    [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [currentViewController release];

    currentViewController = [aViewController retain];
    [self.window addSubview:currentViewController.view];
}

-(IBAction)gotosecondview:(id)sender { 
    [self switchToViewController:[[[secondviewcontroller alloc] init] autorelease]];
}

@end
```

Here, all the logic for maintaining a single `UIViewController` alive lies in the `switchToViewController` method, which also handles the logic for switching from one view to another. As an added bonus, you can quickly add support for animations by adding a couple of lines in `switchToViewController`.

Comment: thanks for that brilliant explanation pgb. Nice piece of code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can not release view in the call.
There is only one thing you can do in such conditions. use Autorelease,

Answer (score 0):

The reason `[second release]` is crashing your code is likely because you're releasing your view controller which in turn releases the second view.  The iPhone cookbook has some sample code on switching/swapping views if that's all that you're trying to accomplish.  Here's the link.  Hope this helps!

[link text](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C04-Building%20Interfaces/03-Switching%20Views)

Comment: Thank You soo much buddy...this link has lot of information. i downloaded all of them , this is will be very much in handy while programming for iphone and ipad. Thanks a ton buddy.